# How can I populate an Android listview using a php service?

Tags: php, android, json, listview

Right now I have a database table "Content" with the columns "title" and "body".

I made a PHP rest service to generate jSON which reads.

```
{"title":"bbhi"}{"title":"jhene aiko and "}{"title":"123456789101112"}{"title":"cats"}{"title":"drizzy"}
```

I'm currently just trying to get the title. It does successfully get all of the contents of my database. I'm not sure if this is the correct form of jSON I need to use for this.

This is the relevant PHP:

```
$sql = "SELECT title FROM Content ORDER BY id DESC";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $response["title"] = $row["title"];
        print(json_encode($response));
    }
    $response["success"] = 1;
} else {
    $response["success"] = 0;
    print(null);
}
```

Now, on the Android side of things I am re-purposing a similar class I used to log the user in. It queries the URL with a GET and (should return) the jSON object. Towards the bottom I populate the Android ListView right now (but with just the same thing it gets over and over again).

I need to be able to have ALL the titles in my jSON object, and I want to be able to iterate through all of the titles and populate my android listview.

This is the relevant Android class for getting the jSON:

> getNotes.java

```
class getNotes extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {

JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

private ProgressDialog pDialog;

private static final String LOGIN_URL = "http://rohanharrison.com/message/androidGetNoteList.php";

private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
private static final String TAG_MESSAGE = "message";
private static final String TAG_TITLE = "title";

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
    pDialog.setMessage("Fetching Notes...");
    pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
    pDialog.setCancelable(true);
    pDialog.show();
}

@Override
protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {

    try {

        HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
        //params.put("name", args[0]);
        //params.put("password", args[1]);

        Log.d("request", "starting");

        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                LOGIN_URL, "GET", params);



        if (json != null) {
            Log.d("JSON result", json.toString());

            return json;
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}

protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {

    int success = 0;
    String message = "";
    ArrayList al = new ArrayList();

    if (pDialog != null && pDialog.isShowing()) {
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }

    if (json != null) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, json.toString(),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        try {
            success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
            message = json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    if (json != null) {
        Log.d("Success!", message);

        final ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.notesList);


        String[] noteTitle = new String[0];
        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < 24; i++) {
                al.add(json.getString(TAG_TITLE).toString());
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        final List<String> notes_list = new ArrayList<String>(al);
        final ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String> (MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, notes_list);
        lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);



    } else {
        Log.d("Failure", message);
    }
}

}
```

For a visual, this is the database: http://imgur.com/a/gakgQ.png

And this is what the Android ListView looks like: http://imgur.com/a/WiRIz.png

I'm new to both Android development and jSON in general, so I'm sorry for my ignorance.

Comment: your visual image link not working

Comment: for best practice generate the title or any json object in json array.

Comment: Not sure what's up with imgur...

Comment: I'll try making it a json array, thanks.